# Window10 Clion, The File was loaded in wrong encoding:UTF-8

Tags: windows, c++11, encoding, clion

When I use clion on windows 10, I open a C++11 project which is downloaded from Internet. I found that the wrong encoding looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmHSk.png)

Comment: Did you try clicking on the `Reload in another encoding` button? What is the encoding of the file? You could try a different editor like Notepad++ to identify and change the encoding if necessary.

Comment: oh，I notice that my image has no description. the tar.gz file I download from website is come from macOS. and my develop machine is Window. It seems that every time i unzip the tar.gz file from macOS, it will create some extra wrong, incomplete cpp & hpp files. and the picture I post is just the wrong one. so delete wrong files is ok~